# Why does mapStateToProps only update in this strange way ? (And what can be done about it ?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-native

Using redux with react-native found that mapStateToProps updates only when another running phone-app window is switched into first.

For example with the test code below expected the steps:

1. Default ***Start*** test text is displayed.
2. Press ***Dispatch Text Action*** button

to yield:

3. Updated ***Changed*** text is displayed instead of ***Start***

instead have:

3. Need to switch to another running app window (Ex: Clock app), and then switch back to development app.
4. Updated ***Changed*** text is displayed instead of ***Start***

The mapStateToProps function doesn't update the component unless we switch back and forth between the app windows first.

Any ideas?

---

### *Test code*

**reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';


const test = (state = 'Start', action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD':
            return('Changed')
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default combineReducers({
    test
})
```

**test action + container**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import TestComp from '../components/TestComp'


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    test: state.test
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
     testDispatch: () => dispatch({type: 'ADD'})
})

export default connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   mapDispatchToProps
)(TestComp)
```

**component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class TestComp extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.test = props.test
        this.testDispatch = props.testDispatch
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                     {this.test}
                </Text>

                <Button
                   title='Dispatch Test Action'
                   onPress={() => this.testDispatch()}
                />
            </View>

        )
    }
}


export default TestComp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are capturing the value of `props.test` in your constructor. This.test is never updated again for the lifecycle of the object, which is why you don't see the updates.

Instead, you should remove `this.test` inside your `TestComp` component and use `this.props.test` instead.

Comment: That was so simple!
Shame I didn't think of it. Thanks!